# Nokogiri seems to miss some tags... why?

Tags: html, ruby, html-parsing, nokogiri

I am using Nokogiri from the command line on the following URL:

```
nokogiri 'http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_default'
```

When that url is loaded into an irb session, the @doc variable contains the Nokogiri Node objects from the parsed HTML, but, it seems to misses all

```
<script async>
```

tags, though it catches

```
<script>
```

tags. Here are the async tags it seems to miss:

```
<script async="" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js">    </script>
<script async="" src="//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script>
<script async="" type="text/javascript" src="http://partner.googleadservices.com/gpt/pubads_impl_48.js"></script>
```

and inconsistently collects `<iframe>` tags (catching 1 of 3):

```
@doc.xpath('//iframe').each{|n| puts n.path}
/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/iframe
```

I want to know why Nokogiri is just parsing all the tags and including them as Nokogiri objects in the `@doc` array.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to check when parsing a document you're not familiar with, is `errors`:

```
>> @doc.errors
[
    [0] #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Element script embeds close tag>,
    [1] #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Misplaced DOCTYPE declaration>,
    [2] #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: htmlParseStartTag: misplaced <html> tag>,
    [3] #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: htmlParseStartTag: misplaced <head> tag>,
    [4] #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: htmlParseStartTag: misplaced <body> tag>
]
```

If there are errors in a document, then Nokogiri attempts to fix them, similar to how a browser would, but its knowledge isn't sufficient to make sense of some situations. That can cause tags to be missed or misplaced.

The document in question has an embedded HTML document inside a `<textarea>` tag. That's not valid HTML. The embedded document should have been encoded to use entities so it would display correctly but not act like true markup.